# Have Winter Bash for Stack Overflow Enterprise

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash, so-enterprise

My company has started using Stack Overflow Enterprise, and it does not have a Winter Bash.  Activity on our site seems a bit light, and I think Winter Bash might be a good way to increase activity on the site.

Comment: I'm really glad you like Winter Bash! This sort of request is something that's best to mention to your company's Enterprise administrator, who can reach out to your Enterprise services contact and that can be sent to the Enterprise dev team. Because of how Enterprise production works, we couldn't add this for this year - and I can't say whether we'd include it in the future or not - but the best chance will be to go through internal contacts. :)

Comment: @Catija  hmmm, that is some Enterprise you describe there :/